# The topbar item background should be less !important

Tags: feature-request, design, top-bar

I'm maintaining a custom Stylish skin for SO *(which I don't want to link to here directly to avoid suspicions of advertising)*, and I've come to find out that the top menu items have a locked-in `background-color` which I can't change with any combination of different selectors and `!important`s.

Conflicting CSS:

> SO stylesheet:
> [image: .topbar .topbar-icon-on, .topbar .topbar-icon-on:hover { background-color: #f0f0f0; }]
>   My custom stylesheet:
> [image: .topbar .topbar-links .profile-me:hover, .topbar .topbar-links .topbar-menu-links a:hover, .topbar .yes-hover:hover, .topbar .topbar-icon-on, .topbar .topbar-icon-on:hover { background-color: #973b62 !important; box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(255,255,255,.5); }]

Result:

> [image: SO Top Navigation Bar Wrong BG]

I tested to see if the `!important` in the SO stylesheet is necessary and from what I can tell it's not, so it should be safe to take it out without breaking site functionality, and also allowing custom styles to modify that color.

Comment: We'll take a look at this, but the reason that styling is in there is that it's a separate .less bake from other things since it's used across many properties outside of Q&A as an include and was necessary there. We may not be able to change this easily but will take a look at least...we don't like using `!important` either.